# In MVC architecture, can a controller and model manage more than one View?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

Can I create 2 views for a model and controller?
My current application is MVC complaint , and it has a single view.

I need to create a second GUI, that fetches few information from the model (updated from the first GUI data) , update it and display back in the first GUI.

Comment: You can add multiple view for single model and controller but each view has its own action in controller

Answer (score 0):

You can have a different view per action. Based on your description, this seems to be what you are looking for. You have different actions for the same model, it's ok.

You can add a new action for the new information that you want to update and click on the right button of the mouse and click "add view". It will add a new view for that action.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is to create other actions, one for each View you want to display.

You can have as many Views as you like, as long as you can route between them.

As default, the line `return View();` or `return View(model)` will look for a view in this path: /Views/{ControllerName}/{ActionName}.
You can also specify the view name, as Controller.View() also accepts a string as the view name.
Knowing this, you could display different views from a single action, according to parameters passed to your action.
Example:

```
public ActionResult Example(bool a)
{
   if (a) return View("a");
   else return View("b");
}
```

this will call the view /Views/{ControllerName}/a.cshtml if a is true and /Views/{ControllerName}/b.cshtml if a is false.
You can also call other partial views or actions from your first view, using html helpers: `@Html.Partial({ViewName})`, `@{Html.RenderPartial({ViewName});}` or `@{Html.RenderAction({ActionName});}`

EDIT:
View() also searchs for /Views/Shared/{ActionName}